# Spring Boot actuator endpoint /prometheus doesn't list the tomcat related metrics, like request count

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, monitoring, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot actuator endpoint /prometheus doesn't list the tomcat related metrics, like request count. But it has metrics like `http_server_requests_seconds_count` and `http_server_requests_seconds_max`.

The endpoint /actuator/metrics/http.server.requests returns the request count metrics -

```
"measurements": [
    {
        "statistic": "COUNT",
        "value": 268.0
    },
    {
        "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
        "value": 6.888039926
    },
    {
        "statistic": "MAX",
        "value": 0.002780578
    }
]
```

We are using Spring Boot 2.x and the actuator dependency is defined as -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 4):

You [need to](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-meter) enable Tomcat’s MBean registry:

> `server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled` must be set to `true` for all Tomcat metrics to be registered

Comment: I used `server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true` in application.properties, still not getting any tomcat related metrics